# Как запустить через командную строку php в Linux

Tags: php, linux

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как запустить через командную строку php в Linux. Я знаю, что в Windows необходимо зайти в папку в php зажать Shift, нажать правую кнопку мыши и из списка выбрать "Открыть окно команд", тогда файлы php с прописанным путем запускаются. Как по такому же принципу запустить в линуксе, потому что пока что постоянно появляется ошибка:

> Could not open input file.

Стоит Linux Mint 18.1, php7 на виртуальной машине VirtualBox

Comment: ctrl+alt+T открывает терминал. пишите php7 полныйПуть/вашфайл.php

Comment: ctrl+alt+T? это в каком линукс/DE?

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой способ - открыть консоль (надежно это сделать через <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> и написав там `xfce4-terminal`, `terminal`, `xterm` - все сильно зависит от Вашего дистрибутива и настроек), зайти в папку с php файлом (при помощи команды `cd`). Многие "проводники" (менеджеры файлов) имеют такой пункт в меню - открыть терминал здесь - также хорошая штука. А в самом терминале написать `php имяфайл.php` и жать enter. На некоторых линуксах нужно выбирать вместо php что то вида php5, php7, php-cli, php5-cli - в целом, пробуйте.

Comment: Товарищи редакторы, пожалуйста, не нужно исправлять консоль на "эмулятор терминала".

Comment: Нужно. Эмулятор терминала и виртуальная консоль - разные "вещи".
Тем самым Вы понижаете компьютерную грамотность, если не понимаете разницы между: виртуальной консолью, эмулятором терминала и псевдотерминальным устройством.

Comment: я знаю разницу в этих всем понятиях. И да, я пишу о консоли, а не виртуальной консоли.

Answer (score 2):

Запустить консоль (`gnome-terminal`, `konsole`, `xterm`) или при помощи `Ctrl+Alt+Fn` перейти в текстовую консоль и там выполнить:

`$ php /path/to/my_script.php`.

Так-же можно, и даже нужно, в начало скрипта написать

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
echo "Hello";
?>
```

После чего сделать скрипт исполняемым :

`$ chmod +x /path/to/my_script.php`

И тогда скрпт можно запускать просто `$ /path/to/my_script.php`

Comment: про #!/usr/bin/env php - это спорно. Зачем? Если у вас какая утилита общего пользования, что ее может потом и bin положишь, то да. Если банальная таска, то лучше явно с php и полным путем, имхо.

Comment: @tcpack4: мы ведь не знаем куда этот скрипт потом поедет - может попадет вообще в нестандартное окружение.

Comment: переедет, тут то разницы нет, что php test.php, что с этой строчкой, причем надо еще executable сделать. ну и в нестандартном окружении может стоят php7 и запускаться только через php7.0 :) все равно в ручную запускать надо.

Comment: @tcpack4: я не настаиваю. Считаете это излишним - ок! Это ваше право.

Comment: @Борис gnome-terminal, konsole & xterm - это эмуляторы терминала.
Ctrl+Alt+F1 - это виртуальная консоль.

Answer (score 1):

Откройте терминал нажатием комбинации <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> или запустите его из главного меню. В открывшемся окошечке введите

```
php /путь/к/вашему/сценарию.php
```

Затем нажмите <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Полный путь к файлу можно скопировать в буфер обмена, выделив требуемый сценарий в файловом менеджере и нажав <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. А чтобы вставить содержимое буфера обмена в терминал, воспользуйтесь сочетанием клавиш <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Убедитесь, что PHP установлен, если не так, в том же окошечке выполните команду

```
sudo apt install php-cli
```

---

Запустить интерактивную сессию PHP можно командой

```
php -a
```

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+T отбычно открывает новую вкладку терминала в существующем.

Comment: @KoVadim, точно, поправил

Comment: Не работает. И знаете почему? потому что Линуксы и DE бывают разные. В своем посте Вы не пишете что именно Вы используете.

Comment: Автор вопроса написала, что у неё Linux Mint 18.1

Comment: Это ещё ровным счетом ничего не значит. Уж поверьте.

Comment: Почему? Конечно, все эти рекомендации (клавиатурных сочетаний) верны лишь для настроек по умолчанию. Но если автор их измененил, то вряд ли возник бы первоначальный вопрос.

Comment: @mymedia на mint по-моему этот шорткат не работает. Лучше указать основной путь открыть Terminal (из меню) и оставить в скобах быстрый способ под убунту сочетанием клавиш.